# What am I missing regarding the simple CORS policy?

Tags: c#, .net-core, cors

Making a post call to the API controller and no matter how to set things up, I get this response in the browser console.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.68.107:8090/api/Files/submitfile' from origin 'http://192.168.68.100:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have a .Net 6 Core API that I want to use in my local network. I have local IIS setup on a small server that I publish the API to. It deploys and mostly functions correctly. I have the CORS policy setup according to the docs.

```
var _policyName = "CorsPolicy";
builder.Services.AddCors(opt =>
    {
        opt.AddPolicy(name: _policyName, builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
        });
    }
);

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors(_policyName);
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

API functions correctly when I launch Localhost and have my front end axios post call submit to it, but it will not work when I publish to the in house web server I have.

I've setup the axios call correctly. I believe I've setup the CORS policy correctly.

Only thing I can think of is the way I have the controller setup.

I have a controller that takes a FromBody parameter and it works perfectly Cross origin. It's here

```
[HttpPost, Route("new-category")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddNewCategory([FromBody] CategoryDto category)
        {
            try
            {
                await _uploadService.SaveNewCategory(category.Category);
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

This controller is the culprit. No matter what I try CORS blocks this ..

```
  [HttpPost, Route("submitfile")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SubmitFile([FromForm] FileUploadModel file)
        {

            try
            {

                if (file.File.Length <= 0)
                    return BadRequest("Empty File");

                //save file
                var fileLocation = await _uploadService.FileUpload(file.File, file.Category);

                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Here's the axios method that calls this controller.. which works when running localhost

```
await axios.post(API + "Files/submitfile", formData, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
```

The above CORS response is what I get. What am I missing here? How can I resolve this error?

Thank you for taking a look. Greatly appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that doesn't work, but I had a similar issue until I bypassed the named policy and applied the requirements in the `UseCors()` method:

```
app.UseCors(policy => {
    policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin();
});
```

Comment: Appreciate the comment. I've tried implementing there as well. Neither way works. Unfortunately.

Comment: The client has to account for the CORS protocol, too. In my app I used JavaScript fetch, specifying `mode: "cors"` in it's "requestInit" object.